# Google play store not showing update option for new apk

Tags: android

I have my app installed in my cell with version 1.0.3 ( Version code 1)  In Google Play Store, I can see my app with version 2.0.1 ( Version code 2 ), but it doesn't show me the button update ( it is showing me the button "Open")  Is it something I have to include in my app???  Is it a bug in Play Store???  Is it a configuration problem???

Comment: Try to clear cache of your Google Play Store and the update button will be shown.

Comment: possible duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086791/google-play-store-showing-open-button-instead-of-update-button/46188555#46188555

Comment: @Subhadarshani Patra did u solve the problem ? i got the same problem and same problem fixing just like u but don't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play Store having new version of the app, but not showing update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020815/play-store-having-new-version-of-the-app-but-not-showing-update)

Answer (score 5):

If u install app using usb debugging mode then in playstore it will not show update when you update app in playstore.

If your previous version also downloaded from playstore then it will show update.

Comment: No its not in debugging mode it's in release mode.we have the older version apk installed in our device.now we have uploaded a higher version to the play store.now when we want to update the app the update option is not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear cache of your Google Play Store and the update button will be shown.

EDIT

As mentioned in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

**Updating system apps**

Users will see system apps (including any pre-loaded apps) in the My Apps section of the Google Play Store as soon as an application with the same package name is uploaded to the Play Console (even if the application is unpublished).

Google Play can manage updates to preloaded applications, provided the following conditions are met:

1. The preloaded app needs to be in the system partition
2. The preloaded app needs to be free
3. The preloaded app needs to be signed with the same signature as the app published in Google Play
4. The package name of the preloaded and updated app needs to be the same
5. The version code of the updated app needs to be greater than that of the preloaded app

Comment: Yes I have tried it also but still the update button is not coming.

Comment: @SubhadarshaniPatra what was the problem in your updation?   I also have same problem