# Play Store showing open button instead of update button

Tags: android, google-play

I have a android app on **play store** say with version 2 and i want to update the app to version 3 now that is done.
But when i go to play store it shows **open button** and not the **update button**

I have even released the apk in the release modes and not on the debug mode

Also i have been through these questions but none answer is satisfactory

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020815/play-store-having-new-version-of-the-app-but-not-showing-update)

[And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086791/google-play-store-showing-open-button-instead-of-update-button)

Please help Thanks in advance...

Comment: It may take a few hours before your update goes through. Also, I often have the latest version of my app already on my phone, in which case I obviously won't see the update button. It might be a good a idea to put the same release build (e.g with the release signature) with a lower version number onto your phone to see if the update button shows up.

Comment: @EndreBörcsök dude i have tested it, and its been more that 24 hrs from the updated version on play store still the same open button

Comment: @EndreBörcsök thanks for your help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK i'm writing this thing here because i **didn't** find any good **concrete answer** for this thing

So play store gives the option of **update** for only those apps which are actually **downloaded (installed)** from play store.
So for all those who run their apps through **usb debug** they could not be benefited of this update facility of play store even if the **app is the same** that is been **uploaded to the play store**.

Now the conclusion that i can draw is that **google play wont give any updates to those apps that are been installed by usb or any other source except google play store...**

Hope it helps anyone who are looking for answers just like me ;)

Comment: @RameshKumar did you understood the answer or you had any problems regarding it???

Comment: I'm not sure if Google has updated this concern lately, but it shows "**Update**" button for me when run via Android Studio also, but have to match these conditions: 1. Change Build variant on Android Studio to release; 2. Temporary reduce **VERSION_CODE** on *build.gralde* to make it **lower** than **VERSION_CODE** of the app on Play Store.

Comment: Snehal I have exactly this problem but I really need to be able to upload the app through google play store. @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce I did what you say I.E. use the release variant and a lower version code, but it still only shows the button "open" for me. Do you have any idea/official docs please