# Google Play Store never shows Update instead of Open

Tags: android, google-play, playback

I've released a new version of an app to google play store.

I see Update button. After the updating i still see Update button instead of Open.

My codeVersion is absolutely higher than the previous version existing in the app store.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: This is the 3rd time at least this has been asked today.  Stop repeating the same question.  Especially as the answer is only "there's a bug in the play store app".

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553534/why-does-my-app-in-google-play-store-urges-to-update-even-though-the-latest-vers#comment94008005_53553534), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568569/play-store-keeps-on-showing-update-option), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571956/app-on-google-play-always-shows-update-instead-of-open#comment94009021_53571956).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.  This question was asked before and it may have been because the developer was using a debug APK.  Are you certain that you are using the signed APK and not the debug version?

[Post from this website with similar question asked:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020815/play-store-having-new-version-of-the-app-but-not-showing-update)