# React Native App update redirect using Linking (bundle release)

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, in-app-update

When the app starts i manually checking the current installed build number with the latest build number which i stored in database, and then if the installed build version number is less then i prompting the user about the app updates with two options 'No thanks' and 'Go to store'. When the user clicks on go to store button i redirecting to the play store using react native Linking like below

```
const PLAY_STORE_LINK = 'market://details?id=' + res[0].appid;

Linking.openURL(PLAY_STORE_LINK).catch(err =>
console.error("An error occurred", err)
);
```

It is actually redirecting to the play store but instead of update button it is showing open button.

when i generate apk and testing it is working fine showing update button but it is not working in bundle release.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try add parameters like there
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#UriSummary

const PLAY_STORE_LINK = 'market://details?id=' + res[0].appid + '&rnd=' + Math.random();

May be its cache?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is play store cache issue, even app all updates are in live, we have to wait for 2 to 3 hrs or have to clear the play store app storage cache.

here is the useful link

[Play Store having new version of the app, but not showing update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020815/play-store-having-new-version-of-the-app-but-not-showing-update)